# BIT: Unable to understand update operation in Binary index Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, bit

I have just read answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439233/bitusing-a-binary-indexed-tree) and was very satisfied and it is indeed a fantastic answer. It taught me the working of BIT.

But at the end, the second last paragraph is where I am struggling. It says,

> Similarly, let's think about how we would do an update step. To do
>   this, we would want to follow the access path back up to the root,
>   updating all nodes where we followed a left link upward. We can do
>   this by essentially doing the above algorithm, but switching all 1's
>   to 0's and 0's to 1's. But if I see, take some example, it does not
>   work just as by simply switching 1's and 0's, according to me.

e.g. lets take we want to update value at node 5 = 101 Switching 1s and 0s, we get 010... Now applying the procedure they have given earlier, we will end up updating some other node or so.

I must be getting it wrong. Please correct me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right.
Use this:

```
                     1
               /           \
         2                      3
      /      \                /     \
   4           5           6          7
 /   \       /   \       /   \       /  \
8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
```

Functions:

`int root(int node_index) { return node_index >> 1 }`

`int left(int node_index) { node_index << 1 }`

`int right(int node_index) { left(node_index) | 1 }`